# show component depending on state

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components that I want to display based on the state.
basically when I click the button I want to toggle 2 components. I dont understand why when I click the button nothing changes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, NavLink, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {isToggleOn: false};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <header>
                {this.state.isToggleOn ? <MenuOpened /> : <MenuClosed />}
            </header>
        )
    }
}

const MenuClosed = () => {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
            {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
        </button>
    )
}

const MenuOpened = () => {
    return(
        <ul>
            <li><NavLink to="/page-1" exact>page1</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/page-2" exact>page2</NavLink></li>

        </ul>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: `MenuClosed` and `MenuOpened` are two different components. You can pass `handleClick` as a prop to these components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gotta pass handleClick function and isToggleOn state as props to MenuClosed component.

```
{this.state.isToggleOn ? <MenuOpened /> : <MenuClosed handleClick={this.handleClick} isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn} />}
```

And then:

```
const MenuClosed = ({handleClick,  isToggleOn}) => { return ( <button onClick={handleClick}> {isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'} </button> ) }
```

Comment: yup that works! i guess Im still confused with what´s a component and what´s not. since these 2 are no extending Component. Am I doing this the right way? looks like I will have to pass handleClick and isToggleOn to the MenuOpened component to do the opposite thing. thank you so much for your help